# Why does it work like that? (IndexOf and LastIndexOf methods)

Tags: c#, .net

I know it may not be a best-practice solution for my problem but I'd tried to remove the first and last specific characters of a string.

Here's a string for example: `"product""`. I'd like to remove only the first and last `"` characters so the expected result would be: `product"`.

Here's my code that produced some unexpected results and I'd like to understand why it is working like that.

```
var productName = "\"product\"\""; // "product""
```

`productName.IndexOf('\"', 0)` and `productName.LastIndexOf('\"', 0)` would be both 0 here at this point.

```
if (productName.IndexOf('\"', 0) == 0) productName = productName.Remove(productName.IndexOf('\"', 0), 1);
```

In this condition, `IndexOf` returns 0 as expected so `productName`'s value will be `productName""` at this point. Then, I run the following:

```
if (productName.LastIndexOf('\"', 0) == 0) productName = productName.Remove(productName.LastIndexOf('\"', 0), 1);
```

In this condition, `LastIndexOf` returns -1. It acts as if my variable's length remains the same after `Remove` but its value is shifted to the left by 1 character. Why is that?

Comment: How did `"product""` become `asd"`?

Comment: Why is your expected result `asd"`?

Comment: That's a typo. I started to write my post with asd in it but then i decided to change it to product so it would actually mean something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the docs for [`string.LastIndexOf(char, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_System_Int32_):

> Reports the zero-based index position of the last occurrence of a specified string within this instance. The search starts at a specified character position and proceeds backward toward the beginning of the string.
>
> ...
>
> **startIndex**
>       `Int32`
>
> The search starting position. The search proceeds from startIndex toward the beginning of this instance.

You're calling:

```
productName.LastIndexOf('\"', 0)
```

So you're starting at the first character in your string (index 0), and proceeding towards the beginning looking for a `"` character. But you're already *at* the beginning! So you're not going to find anything.

Just use the overloads which don't take a `startIndex`: you don't need it:

```
string.IndexOf('"')
string.LastIndexOf('"')
```

Comment: alternativly - if OP really wants the index-based approach - use the strings length as startindex on `LastIndex`.

Comment: @FoltánDániel It makes more sense for it to start at the end: then it can stop as soon as it finds a matching character, rather than having to scan the whole string

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var productName = "\"product\"\"";
        if (productName.IndexOf('\"', 0) == 0)
            productName = productName.Remove(productName.IndexOf('\"', 0), 1);

        if (productName.LastIndexOf('\"', productName.Length-1) == productName.Length - 1)
            productName = productName.Remove(productName.LastIndexOf('\"', productName.Length - 1), 1);
```